# Hide Scrollview behind Imageview and vice-versa in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-imageview, android-scrollview

I am an amateur in android studio and kotlin. I am implementing a dashboard where I have frame layout as the bodylayout and is replaced by different fragments when each item on the bottomnavigationview is clicked. However, for one particular item I need to use two view, imageview and a scrollview. So, when the progress bar in the scrollview contains no progress, I have to show the Imageview hiding the scrollview and also disabling the scroll at that time. But When there is some progress in the progressbar in the scrollview, scrollview with it's content should be shown and not the imageview.

I have seen some answers int he same context but it didn't work for me. So, I would like to know how to do it? Am I doing it wrong.

The code snippet is below.

```
class ProgressFragment : Fragment() {

val TAG = "ProgressFragment"
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_progress, container, false)
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    progress_progressbar2?.setProgress(5)
    progress_progressbar2?.max=15

    if (progress_progressbar2?.progress!!.equals(0)){
        started_image?.bringToFront()
        progress_scrollview?.invalidate()
    }
    else{
        progress_scrollview?.bringToFront()
        started_image?.invalidate()
        navigation_header_container?.setImageResource(R.drawable.header_pink)
    }
  }
}
```

I am calling this fragment in the mainactivity and replacing the framelayout with this fragment in the mainactivity.

The activity_main.xml layout is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@mipmap/bg"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/navigation_header_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="65dp"
android:scaleY="1.5"
android:scaleX="2"
android:src="@drawable/header_green"
/>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_nav"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/navigation_header_container"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorWhite"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_item_colors"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation">

</android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/header_text"
    android:layout_width="156dp"
    android:layout_height="39dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="#200"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="TextView" />
<!--app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_item_colors"-->
<!--app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_item_colors"-->


</RelativeLayout>
```

The progress layout is given below.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ProgressFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/progress_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/progress_parentrelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/progress_child1relayout"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="280dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/quadrant1_textview1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="60sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Min"
                android:textColor="#200"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress_progressbar1"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/customprogressbar" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/progress_child2relayout"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="280dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/progress_child1relayout">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/quadrant2_textview1"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="40sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                android:text="Challenge Status"
                android:textColor="#200"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress_progressbar2"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/customprogressbar" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/quadrant2_textview2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
                android:text="Completed"
                android:textColor="#200"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/quadrant2_textview3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
                android:text="open"
                android:textColor="#200"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/quadrant2_textview4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="230dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#200"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/progress_child3relayout"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="280dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progress_child1relayout">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/quadrant3_textview1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="60sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#200"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/progress_child4relayout"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="280dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/progress_child3relayout"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progress_child2relayout">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/quadrant4_textview1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="60sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                android:text="Pods Mastered"
                android:textColor="#200"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar.MaterialProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/circularprogress"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
                android:progress="20" />
            <!--<ProgressBar-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/progress_progressbar3"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_marginTop="120dp"-->
            <!--android:layout_marginLeft="50sp"-->
            <!--android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/ringprogressbar"-->
            <!--android:max="100"-->
            <!--android:progress="20"-->
            <!--style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge" />-->

        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/whatdoesthis_mean"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="580dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="What does this mean?"
            android:textColor="#200"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/child_button"
            android:layout_width="344dp"
            android:layout_height="79dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="620dp"
            android:src="@drawable/pinkcolor"
            android:text="child name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/child_name_text"
            android:layout_width="184dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Child Name"
            android:textColor="#190fdf"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/started_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/letsgetstarted"
    android:background="#ebcac3c7"
    />

</FrameLayout>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are setting the Progress as 5 in `onCreate` first itself. So it will never go to the if case there, right? Do you dynamically change the progress later?

Comment: @VishnuSP True. But I am an error of KotlinNullPointerException at the if condition case. Moreover, I will be setting the progress dynamically but just to check I have done it this way and I have found that I am unable to get the scrollview front and hide the imageview. The other problems are that the progress is not shown and the I am able to scroll even when the imageview is in the front.

Comment: NPE is because your progress_progressbar2 is an optional. You can use the elvis operator to handle it. Can you  please share your layout also?

Comment: @VishnuSP I have added the layouts as well. I solved the NPE by removing the "!!" and simply using "==" operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragments don't create the view in `OnCreate` unlike the Activity. The same can be understood through the life-cycle of a fragment. Moreover, this is one of the major differences between an activity life-cycle and a fragment life-cycle. So, instead of assigning the values in the `OnCreate`, it should be done in `OnViewCreated`.

The code snippet could be modified to:

```
class ProgressFragment : Fragment() {

val TAG = "ProgressFragment"
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_progress, container, false)
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    progress_progressbar2?.setProgress(12)
    progress_progressbar2?.max=15
    val currentProgress = progress_progressbar2?.progress ?: 0
    if (currentProgress == 0){
        started_image?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        progress_scrollview?.visibility = View.GONE
    } else {
        started_image?.visibility = View.GONE
        progress_scrollview?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        navigation_header_container?.setImageResource(R.drawable.header_pink)
    }
  }
}
```

The condition and static/dynamic progress assignment can be done in the `OnResume` method also.

Thank you Vishnu.

Answer (score -1):

```
val currentProgress = progress_progressbar2?.progress ?: 0
if (currentProgress == 0){
    started_image?.visibility = VISIBLE
    progress_scrollview?.visibilty = GONE
} else {
    started_image?.visibility = GONE
    progress_scrollview?.visibilty = VISIBLE
    navigation_header_container?.setImageResource(R.drawable.header_pink)
}
```

Instead of `bringToFront` you manage it using the `visibility` of the views.

Android Documentation : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)

Try this out

Comment: I have already tried this, Nevertheless I tried it again and the problem still persists.

Comment: Please share a screenshot of the issue.

Comment: Thank you bro. I figured it out. I'll write it as the answer.